# why react skips displaying values in component?

Tags: reactjs

```
    <div className = 'card'> 
      <p>{props.rate.code} {props.rate.currency}</p>
      <p>{props.rate.mid}
      {console.log(props.code)}</p>
    </div>
)
```

In console.log i can see all codes, but on site displays only random few, which changes if i refresh.
I really don't have any idea, this is code from tutorial, but I work on another dataset.
I have 2 dimensional table with data
way i get data

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/A/?format=json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(values =>this.setState({currency: values}))
    fetch('http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/B/?format=json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(values =>this.setState({currency: values}))
    fetch('http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/C/?format=json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(values =>this.setState({currency: values}))
  }
```

using map

```
    {props.currency.map(
          (table,index) =>
            table.rates.map(rate =>(
              <Card key={index+rate.code} rate={rate}/>
            )
          )
        )}
```

in app component

```
<CardList currency={this.state.currency}/>
```

in console i see maybe 200 values,
but on site i see randomly 10-100 values

Comment: More information required.

Comment: I guess this happens because you pass falsy values to JSX when JSX skips such values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each fetch overwrites the previous `currency` state, this way you loose previous data. To avoid you would need to copy the current state while adding the new one:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/A/?format=json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(values =>this.setState(({ currency }) => {currency: [...currency, ...values]}))
    fetch('http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/B/?format=json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(values =>this.setState(({ currency }) => {currency: [...currency, ...values]}))
    fetch('http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/C/?format=json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(values =>this.setState(({ currency }) => {currency: [...currency, ...values]}))
  }
```

though this looks a little dirty, since you are doing several state updates. You could await each response, then update your state:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const currencyA = await this.getCurrencyFromTable('A');
      const currencyB = await this.getCurrencyFromTable('B');
      const currencyC = await this.getCurrencyFromTable('C');
      const currency = [...currencyA, ...currencyB, ...currencyC];

      this.setState({ currency })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  getCurrencyFromTable(table) {
    return fetch(`http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/${table}/?format=json`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
  }
```

Comment: you are welcome :) if you feel that answers your question you could mark it as accepted answer. cheers!